# Subview doesn't get to the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview

I have a `UIButton` subclass which contains a `UITextView` and two `UILabels` I create them doing the following:

```
UILabel *authorName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, viewHeight, viewWidth, 16)];
authorName.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.5];
authorName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
authorName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
authorName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"username"]];
[self addSubview:authorName];

UILabel *likes = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewWidth-50, viewHeight-20, 50, 20)];
likes.backgroundColor = authorName.backgroundColor;
likes.textColor = authorName.textColor;
likes.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
likes.font = authorName.font;
likes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Likes: %@", [data objectForKey:@"likes"]];
[self addSubview:likes];

UITextView *postText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight)];
postText.editable = NO;
postText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectForKey:@"text"]];
postText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
postText.backgroundColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
```

The problem is with the last one *`postText`* which uses the `frame` of the subclass *`UIButton`*, I want to use that button, by adding this `postText` to the bottom of `subviews`, because if it's on the top I will not be able to tap on the button.

I tried to use

```
[self bringSubviewToFront:self];
```

And

```
[self sendSubviewToBack:postText];
```

And

```
[self insertSubview:postText aboveSubview:authorName];
```

And, finally

```
[self insertSubview:postText atIndex:0];
```

But none of them work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that the `UIButton` is the parent view here, every subview you add is *on top of* the `UIView` that is the `UIButton`.  So things like:

```
[self bringSubviewToFront:self];
```

of course won't work because `self` isn't a `subview` of `self`

**Really what you should be doing here is not subclassing `UIButton` for this**.  You should make a custom `UIView` class `MyFancyButtonThing` that does what you want by putting the `UIButton` view on top of all the other subviews of `MyFancyButtonThing`.